# Change Foreground in ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection of the class's objects `UrlCount`:

```
public ObservableCollection<UrlCount> URLsCount { get; set; }
public class UrlCount
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

This collection is are `ItemSsource` of one `ListView` :

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="ListUrlView" ItemsSource="{Binding URLsCount}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Url}"/>
                        <Run Text=" : "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I need to Change `Foreground` in `ListViewItem` if `Count` = -1. I try this :

```
<ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ListUrlView, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

But none of the `ListViewItems` are not changed his `Foreground`. I haven't  any Idea, how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `DataTrigger` in the `ListView`'s `ItemContainerStyle` like so:

```
 <ListView Margin="10" Name="ListUrlView" ItemsSource="{Binding UrLsCount}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Url}"/>
                    <Run Text=" : "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count}" Value="-1">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

**Update**

Dont Forget to set your `DataContext`

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

and to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, here the full sample's codebehind:

```
public class UrlCount
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<UrlCount> _urLsCount =new ObservableCollection<UrlCount>()
    {
        new UrlCount()
        {
            Count = 1,
            Url = "Url1"
        },
        new UrlCount()
        {
            Count = -1,
            Url = "Url2"
        },
    };
    public ObservableCollection<UrlCount> UrLsCount
    {
        get { return _urLsCount; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _urLsCount)) return;
            _urLsCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

*Result*

[image]

Comment: Set your DataContext correctly and make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface

Comment: I already have DataContext and implementation INPC. The `ListView` are filled correctly, but color doesn't set right. All `ListViewItems` = are black

Comment: Are you setting the Foreground somewhere else?

Comment: yep, in DataTemplate... It was my fail (